# react firebase - filtering firebase fetched items by user uid value

Tags: reactjs, firebase

In my react app i fetch a list of items from Firebase to show in a listview.

```
    this.fb = new Firebase(rootUrl + 'items/');
    this.bindAsObject(this.fb, 'items');
    this.fb.on('value', this.handleDataLoaded);
```

Each item has a value of a uid for a user who posted it.

I use `authData.uid` in the app to get the logged in users uid.

How can i go about filtering the list to show only the projects by that user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a `snapshot` to filter lists? It is way more efficient...

Here's how to use one:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://YOUR-URL.firebaseio.com/");
    ref.orderByChild("location").equalTo("United States").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      document.write(snapshot.key());
    console.log(snapshot.key());
    });
```

You've asked: "How can i go about filtering the list to show only the projects by that user?"

The above is simply an example. In your case, **replace** `location` with `project`, or whatever parameter type you have stored in your database (at `https://YOUR-URL.firebaseio.com/`), and `United States` will be **replaced** by the user name, id, or **whatever parameter value you have stored for that user to be identified in code**.

> A basic Firebase query starts with one of our orderBy functions:
>   `orderByChild()`, `orderByKey()`, or `orderByPriority()`. You can then
>   combine these with five other methods to conduct complex queries:
>   `limitToFirst()`, `limitToLast()`, `startAt()`, `endAt()`, and
>   `equalTo()`. Figure out which function to use.

**See here for more details on how to use a snapshot**: [firebase.com/blog/2014-11-04-firebase-realtime-queries.html](http://firebase.com/blog/2014-11-04-firebase-realtime-queries.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. How would i actually get the filtered results into the bindAsObject as the function above does? The function i have now gets all the items into the array.

Comment: Your welcome. Use a `equalTo()` as I've said to search your database for a user, get the project. Do you understand? Could you please mark my answer as accepted and vote it up if my answer solved/helped you? Let me know any other questions here in the comment box, please, and I'll update my answer if necessary. Thanks, Chris!

Comment: No problem. What im looking to do is get multiple projects by the user into the this.bindAsObject(this.fb, 'items'); like above. I hope im explaining it clearly enough.

Comment: Figured it out. 'this.bindAsObject(this.fb.orderByChild("user").equalTo(authData.uid), 'items'); Thanks for the help